# Office Add-in SSO AzureAD Word online

Tags: single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to get SSO working from the samples provided here https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/main/Samples/auth I have also tried to do it manually as per the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart

But regardless of what documentation or samples I follow it always falls back to the the login dialog and doesn't SSO. I find this particularly odd when I am using the add-in in Word online from a document library in SharePoint Online. But regardless of whether I am using Word (desktop) or Word (online) it never does the SSO.

Is there a configuration step I am missing? Do I need to enable something in the tenant, other than registering the app in AzureAD, or elsewhere to get SSO to work?

Comment: If SSO fails, it should return a 5 digit error beginning with "13" (13nnn). What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @RickKirkham, I must have broken something, in all of the solutions I tried. as I started a new yo Office project and it has all worked. Not sure what I did to break it. Thanks for the tip around the error code to. Appreciated